How to set a query in DynamoDB where I am using begins_with AND between?
I want to query a dynamodb Table and I want to retrive and filter data using KeyConditionExpression and FilterExpression. Following the code below, how is the appropriate way to acomplish that?
getMyFunction = async (fromNumber = null, toNumber = null, startDate = null, endDate = null, size = null) => {
  const client = getClient();

  try {
      const index = fromNumber ? 2 : 3;
      let searches = [];

      // ...
      
      let attributes = {
          ":gsipk": { S: (fromNumber ? this.getGSI2PK() : this.getGSI3PK()) },
          ...(fromNumber ? { ":from": { S: fromNumber } } : { }),
          ...(!fromNumber && toNumber ? { ":to": { S: toNumber } } : { }),
          ":startdate":startdate,
          ":enddate": enddate
      };

      const result = await client
          .query({
              TableName: process.env.DB_TABLE_NAME,
              IndexName: `GSI${index}`,
              KeyConditionExpression: `GSI${index}PK = :gsipk AND begins_with(GSI${index}SK, :${(fromNumber ? 'from' : 'to')})`,
              FilterExpression: `GSI${index}PK = :gsipk BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate`,
              ExpressionAttributeValues: attributes,
              ScanIndexForward: false
          })
          .promise();

      searches = result.Items.map((item) => unmarshall(item))
      return [null, searches ];
  } catch (error) {
      return [error];
  }
}


Your KeyConditionExpression is fine, but your FilterExpression is not.
You cannot filter on a partition key, you've already told DynamoDB that you want all items that you want GSI${index}PK = :gsipk. If you want to filter based on the partition key further, you have to do it on the client side.

I just want to get the KeyConditionExpression filtered by startDate and endDate. Using the same partition key. Ideally it should be like this GSI${index}PK = :gsipk AND begins_with(GSI${index}SK, :${(fromNumber ? 'from' : 'to')}) BETWEEN :startdate AND :enddate but dynamo do not allow that. How should I add the correct BETWEEN condition in the FilterExpression?

You don't need BEGINS_WITH. Just use BETWEEN, its ordered lexicographically ans will still be correct.
